# Python3.5 subprocess run cat command without using shell

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, cat

I am running `cat` command to read the Linux version using `subprocess.run()`. However it doesn't work, the error is: `cat: '/etc/*-release': No such file or directory`, and I can not use `shell=True` due to security. Any hints how to solve this is appreciated.
Here is my code:

```
try:
    result = subprocess.run(
        shlex.split("cat /etc/*-release"),
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        universal_newlines=True)
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired as err:
    result = err
```

Comment: using `cat` is slightly overkill when you have python to read the files...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: *slightly* overkill?

Comment: but maybe OP has simplified the issue. Well, one can always hope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the role of the shell to evaluate the `*`. If you don't use it, you need to do it yourself, `glob` can help you for that.

So you can fix your example by doing:

```
from glob import glob
try:
    result = subprocess.run(
        ["cat"] + glob("/etc/*-release"),
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        universal_newlines=True)
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired as err:
    result = err
```

Comment: are we sure redirecting both output & error to `PIPE` cannot deadlock?

Comment: BTW there's no timeout possible here.

Comment: The first argument can be `'cat'`, not `'/bin/cat'` -- a PATH lookup will happen as necessary.

Comment: I have not come across deadlock issues, however, this solution throws the same error.

Comment: @PayamMesgari, what does `glob('/etc/*-release')` return if you run it on its own at the REPL (after the `import` line in this answer)? It would only be *the same* error if that glob expression returns the original string.

Comment: It returns a list with two items in it

Comment: @PayamMesgari, ...are those items names of files that actually exist? If they exist, and you're passing them on the command line to `cat` (as this answer tells you to), then how/why would it actually throw a `No such file or directory` error?

Comment: @PayamMesgari, ...anyhow, if `'/etc/*-release'` isn't one of the results in that list, then you can't possibly be getting `cat: '/etc/*-release': No such file or directory` as the resulting error if you're using this code verbatim.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre How would we deadlock by piping both `stderr` and `stdout` to the same pipe? There might be issues having two different writers to the same pipe, but dead-lock is not one of them, as far as I can understand.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Now I have a doubt about this. Doesn't `run` perform a `communicate` internally? The quote I copied is from the `call` function. legacy functions don't do that but `run` does. Why wouldn't it after all? Anyone can implement it using `Popen` and `communicate`.

Comment: (note that my first comment was rather interrogative, not affirmative). Interesting.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, ...reading the Python 3.6 source, it does indeed look like it does the Right Thing. I'm going to need to track back which version the docs quoted previously refer to.

Comment: it's the same documentation page, but it only applies to `call` and `check_call`

Answer (score -3):

You can use the bash command so the * can be evaluated:

```
process =  subprocess.run(['bash', '-i', '-c',  'cat /etc/*-release'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: This entirely defeats the purpose of the exercise. `shell=True` will prefix your argument list with `['sh', '-c']`; if the OP were fine with a shell (which they shouldn't be), they could have just used that.